# plot overlaps using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am learning matplotlib.

I am trying to plot two below plots in a single plot using matplotlib.

[image]

[image]

But it overlaps.
[image]

Here is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train_error = [0.26462888486225206, 0.26462383329393313, 0.2628674962680674, 0.2553700231555298, 0.17473717177688022, 0.14773444580059242, 0.1468299949185866, 0.1468235689407127, 0.1439370366766204]
test_error = [0.8438224756653776, 0.8442034650577578, 1.018608707726192, 4.853704454584892, 123.69312582226338, 798.4569874115062, 3205.5264038946007, 9972.587330411312, 10787335.618580218]

plt.plot(train_error)
plt.plot(test_error)
plt.show()
```

Where am i doing wrong ? Can anyone please **guide / help** ?

Comment: Do you want two separate plots in one figure (like your first result, but grouped together)? Or so you want both lines to appear in a single graph (like your second result, but with vertical space between the lines)? If the second is what you want, then you should probably use a log scale or use a different y axis for the second line. `test_error` has values from 0 to 1e7 (10,000,000) and `train_error`  has values from 0.14 to 0.27. If you plot them with a single, linear y axis, `train_error` and most of `test_error` will look like zero, as shown in your second example.

Comment: When you are plotting values over such a wide range, you will probably do best using a log scale. Otherwise variations in the small values become invisible, as shown in both of your plots of `test_error`.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp I want like second result. Could you please guide how to logscale?

Comment: I think you can just use `plt.yscale('log')` as shown at https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#logarithmic-and-other-nonlinear-axes.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp Yes, this works. Tqsm.

Answer (score 1):

Use the subplot

Go check https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

```
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(train_error)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(test_error)
```

in plt.subplot(a,b,x) you have a,b that represents the number of (row and column) you want vertically and horizontally and x the index of the subplot selected counting from left to right and top to bottom.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. But unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Ho my bad, change the 2nd plt.subplot(1,2,1) by plt.subplot(1,2,2). And if the look doesn't please you you can make them stack vertically with plt.subplot(2,1,x) instead

Comment: this plots two plots side by side. i want in a one plot. i can see my train_erro &est_error values are sparse. do i need to normalize them ?

Comment: The `sharex` example in that documentation is probably a good solution for this problem.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp again it is another plot just below to first one. but i need both train_error & test_error in only one figure.

Comment: I see now if you just want to see them overlap you can normalize yes but you can also use a 2 axis plot, on the left your scale will be for your train_erro and the left will be at scale for your est_error. Take a look here: https://matplotlib.org/2.2.5/gallery/api/two_scales.html . This way you keep a way to need the true values graphically.